# Filter by updated_at - Magento 1.6

Tags: filter, soap, magento-1.6

everyone. How's it going?

I need help with a filter issue. It's not working as I expected.

I'm trying to list orders from after 2023-12-06, but it's returning orders from 2019, 2020, 2021, etc.

Can anyone assist me? Below is the XML I'm using in SOAP UI for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<salesOrderListRequestParam xmlns="urn:Magento">
  <sessionId xmlns="">da775ed86e36c8f553208368e7a1d06f</sessionId>
  <filters xmlns="">
    <complex_filter>
      <filtersComplex_filter>
        <key>state</key>
        <value>
          <key>in</key>
          <value>Processing</value>
        </value>
      </filtersComplex_filter>
      <filtersComplex_filter>
        <key>updated_at</key>
        <value>
          <key>gteq</key>
          <value>2023-12-06 00:00:00</value>
        </value>
      </filtersComplex_filter>
    </complex_filter>
  </filters>
</salesOrderListRequestParam>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```